# MailChimp get subscribers from automation segment

Tags: php, api, email

I've got this MailChimp automation running with let's say 2 mails in it. Everyone from the list gets the first email, the second email is only send when someone clicked a link in the first email (is a setting in MailChimp). Now I have to compare email address entries vs the subscribed emails in the 2nd list. Is it possible to get the 2nd email's subscribers with the MailChimp API?

Have looked trough the docs and didn't really find anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a list of subscribers that were sent email 2 is wanted here.

1: Get the Automation {workflow_id}

```
GET https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/automations/
```

2: Get workflow emails as well as their “id” (the email id for position 2 in this case)

```
GET https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/automations/{workflow_id}/emails
```

3: Take that email “id” (which is actually a Campaign ID) and use it in the reports call below.

4: Return list of subscribers that were sent email 2.

```
GET: https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/reports/{campaign_id}/sent-to
```